# How to access coredata file from another application

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, ios7

I have an ios application in that I am using coredata file for saving and displaying records, now I want to use my first application's coredata in my another ios application, so when my new application launches I want to fetch the coredata file of the existing application. How can i do this. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use iCloud to store your Core Data files / data store contents. Or, if you are just sharing periodically / on demand, preferably store an exported version of your data store rather than storing the Core Data files directly.